# Correct way to use a constant in several unrelated functions

Tags: python, oop, functional-programming

I have a few variables I would like to treat as constants because they never change and are used by tons of different functions in my project. I need to be able to access the constants from several different modules, and the advice I found suggested putting the constants into my `config.py` and then use `from config import CONSTANT1` in each module.

My question is this: I'm not sure of the most Pythonic way to actually use a constant in this situation? Are any of the below example options correct, or maybe it depends on what you're trying to do? Is there a different *correct* way I haven't thought of?

```
def fake_function(x, y):
    # Problem: function relies on the module-level environment for an input
    # (Seems sloppy)
    return (x + y + CONSTANT1)

def fake_function2(x, y, z=CONSTANT1):
    # Problem: seems redundant and as if there was no point in declaring a constant
    # Also you end up with way too many parameters this way
    return (x + y + z)

class Fakeness(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.z = CONSTANT1
    def fake_sum(self, x, y):
        return (x + y + self.z)
        # Problem: I suspect this might be the correct implementation - but 
        # I hope not because my understanding of OOP is weak :) I also don't
        # think this helps me with my many functions that have nothing to do
        # with each other but happen to use the same constants?
```

Comment: I don't understand what you think is wrong with the first option.

Comment: I'm really just checking to see if it *is* considered correct :) My understanding of functions is somewhat influenced by `R` and reading about functional programming and I've been left a bit mixed-up about whether or not it's appropriate to rely on the global (or in this case, module-level) environment at all or if functions need to be self-contained. I am also interested in starting to unit test my work (which I don't know how to do yet) and I'm unclear if relying on a constant is a bad idea/will end up introducing bugs that are hard to understand

Comment: IME unit testing is only made complicated when you rely on _mutable_ global state. Constants don't change during the lifetime of your program, so referring to them inside a function doesn't increase the number of potential code paths. They're no worse than directly using literal values, in that respect.

Comment: You might find the ActiveState recipe titled [**_Constants in Python_**](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65207-constants-in-python/) useful.

Comment: Helpful, thanks martineau and Kevin. Found some good information about mutable global state (like this [link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)) that clarified things even further - I appreciate the references and key words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that, and it's common. Also common, and often more convenient, is to use/abuse class as a namespace, so you have one thing to import and one place to potentially change how your constants work. I do things like:

```
class Settings(object):
    TIMEOUT = 4
    RETRY = 2
    SECRET_KEY = 'foobar'
```

Then you can import Settings, pass it around, or if you need to later, even change what happens when you ask for or set Settings.FOO by working with getattr or metaclass hackery. Just a nice bit of future proofing.